# Making JavaScript not work when clicked for the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
<form method="get" >
   <input type="text" name="keyword" id="map">
   <img src="style/keyboard.png" id="click"/>
   <button type="submit">Search</button> 
</form>
```

And this javascript thing, adopted from [here](http://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/index.html), whose job is showing the virtual keyboard when the `img` is clicked:

```
$('‪#‎map‬').keyboard({
layout: 'custom',
customLayout: {
'default': [ 
    '\u0192(h):lower_case_function_(type_h) \n\
    \u0393(h):lower_case_gamma_(type_h) \n\
    \u0394(h):lower_case_delta_(type_h)\n\ 
',
'{shift} {accept} {cancel}'
],
'shift': [
    '\u03C6(h):lower_case_phi_(type_h) \n\
    \u03C7(h):lower_case_chi_(type_h) \n\
    \u03C8(h):lower_case_psi_(type_h) \n\ 
',
'{shift} {accept} {cancel}'
]
},
usePreview: false,
openOn:null
})
.addTyping();
$('‪#‎click‬').click(function() {
$('#map').getkeyboard().reveal();
});
```

They work fine.
But,

The problem is when the `img` is clicked for the second time, it doesn't hide the virtual keyboard. What I want is when the `img` is clicked, the keyboard appears. When it's clicked again (twice), the keyboard disappears. When it's clicked for the third time, the keyboard reappears.

How do I do that?
I've googled for this issue and still have no idea what to do.
Thanks..

**EDITED:**
**Solved by using answer from @Arjun Vachhani**

```
$("#click").toggle(
    function()
    {
        $('#map').getkeyboard().reveal();
    },
    function() {
        $('#map').getkeyboard().close();
    });
```

Comment: Are you using some plugin?

Comment: Yea, some jquery plugins. Just how the link (view-source:http://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/index.html) shows me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jquery toggle

```
$("#id").toggle(
     function () 
     {
          alert("action 1");
     },
     function () {
          alert("action 2");
     });
```

just paste code in first function that should handle the odd number of click event
and paste code in second function that handles even number of clicks
it will work

Comment: I did this `$('‪#‎click‬').toggle(
        function() {
            $('#map').getkeyboard().reveal();
        },
        function() {
            $('#map').getkeyboard().close(true);
        });`
But still doesn't work. None of the clicks are working. ~.~

Comment: hey, you may be changed html content or changed listener. you can find live example at http://jsfiddle.net/NEfWt/

Comment: what does true in close means ?

Comment: IDK, I just do what I interpret from the tutorials.
I did it by understanding your answer. Thanks :) I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML is changing after the first click, this won't work at second time:

```
$('‪#‎click‬').click(function() {...
```

Try to use jquery .on(), beacuse the click works when the element is in DOM.

add an Id to your form:

```
$("‪form#myform‬").on("click","img#‎click",function() {...
```

or just:

```
 $("‪form").on("click","img#‎click",function() {...
```

[Jquery .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

First time triggers both, but second time only the .on() works.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u4S9j/2/)

Comment: I did what you told me, but now the virtual keyboard doesn't appear, even on the first click. :(

Comment: I added a sample at the end. It should work, there was an unclosed tag:  <input type="text" name="keyword" id="map"> and your id names was not correct at the first time, i retyped them, and after the fiddle has worked. Try it.